# Cannot reduce the height of kendo grid in asp.net mvc

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using 2 Kendo Grids to show some data. One Grid is above followed by 2nd grid
I want to reduce the height of grids
Given the code
**.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 350px;" })**
It worked but the pagination part remains at the same position

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid has a function called "Height".  Just use

.Height(350)